# How to match two 3D models in JavaFX 8/C++?

Tags: java, c++, 3d, javafx-8

I have two models in different position. The aim is to match them to each other (to register). The particular feature is that this two models can be absolutely equal(have the same points and faces, but different translation and rotation), and also have different amount of points or, for example, be practically equal (have little differences with the original model). How it can be done? What algorithms can be used? Especially I'm interested in JavaFX realization, but C++ one is also suitable.

Comment: JavaFX 2.0 perhaps which is the latest.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, JavaFX 8. Now it's beta, release date - march, 2014. See here - [JDK8](https://jdk8.java.net/)

Comment: Sorry, where does it say JavaFX 8?  I see JDK 8.

Comment: @PeterLawrey JavaFX 8 is a part of Java 8 (JDK8).

Comment: Ok, I don't understand what the problem is when having multiple models, but I suggest you try JavaFX 2 first as this is immature enough.  You can use this for 3D visualization.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have two models: one original, and one with some transformations (rotation, translation etc.). So I need to find these transformations, so I will be able to do reverse ones and to match these models.